# Formula Adjustment to IF Function

Tags: excel, if-statement, find

I ran into something unexpected after creating a spreadsheet.

I currently have a formula that lookups the text "A Term" within a cell.

```
=IF(FIND("A Term",P2),"A Term",0)
```

I need this formula to also look for the text "Full Term".

In other words, I need it to say "A Term" if either the text "A Term" or "Full Term" is located within the cell, P2.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is (literally) in your question: an `OR` statement:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("A Term",P2)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Full Term",P2))),"A Term",0)
```

Note that `FIND` is case sensitive, if you want a case insensitive search, use `SEARCH`

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A Term",P2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Full Term",P2))),"A Term",0)
```